# Problema al declarar dependencias(Navigation, Android Studio -Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, navigation

soy nuevo e intento aprender pero, intento hacer una app con la cual pueda navegar entre activities o fragments, para esto un usuario me recomendó usar Navigation, lo busque en Android Developers y lo encontré, pero al momento de querer agregar una dependencia para comenzar a agregar los fragments y para poder hacer esto necesito agregar unas líneas de código en el **Build.Gradle** pero al agregarlas y presionar el la opción de **Sync Now** me sale un error o errores[image: Error]. Copie el error pero eran demasiadas líneas de código, espero que esto sirva para.

Incluso dejaré el link de donde lo saque: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation?authuser=2

Comment: Procura mostrar los errores como texto. En imagenes es más difícil de leer y hay usuarios que ni siquiera pueden verlas. Como sea, el mensaje dice que la variable `nav_version` no está definida. Probablemente te faltó copiar esta línea `def nav_version = "2.3.5"`

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, pero eran como 170 líneas de código. Y si era usar el **def**. es que las líneas decían para kotlin: usar el VAL. Gracias!

Comment: Ah si pero se refiere al lenguaje del archivo `build.gradle`. Se puede escribir en Kotlin pero por default viene en Groovy, incluso si tu app está en Kotlin. Tenlo en cuenta para el futuro: tus archivos de configuración están escritos en un lenguaje llamado Groovy

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta e investigaré sobre este lenguaje Groovy!